# Running application on emulator running older SDK

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a project that builds against Android v2.1 . I can run it fine on a phone running 1.5 but when I try to launch it with an emulator running 1.5, the emulator doesn't show up on the list of available AVDs. I have the `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>` tag in my manifest but it doesn't make a difference. Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out building against the Google APIs for version 2.1 will let you run on older emulator sdks, using just 2.1 core libraries won't let you do this.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to open the Run Configurations settings, and then in the Target tab, to choose "Manual".  When you run, you will get a dialog box allowing you to start any of the installed AVDs or to run in an existing AVD (if any are already running).

Answer (score 1):

The older sdk emulators have a big red X but i was able to click on them anyway. It feels like running a stop sign, but it works :D

Answer (score 0):

Run Configuration settings don't solve the problem. You need to open some other Android project with lower SDK target, launch emulator there and then it allows you to launch app from project with higher SDK target.

I'm using this for project with SDK 10 running on SDK 8 emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The trick i used to run was

1. Open "Android Virtual Device Manager", showing all my emulators.
2. Select the emulator, i want my application to run on.
3. Click Start button to run my selected the emulator first.
4. With target emulator already running in background, ran my application and choose already running emulator to install my app on it.

Worked for me